# How can we add subtitles in video view in android 4.2.2?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
        MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        } 
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoViewActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);
            InputStream i = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
            videoview.addSubtitleSource(i ,MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/srt",Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage()));

            videoview.start();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();



    }


}
```

> The above code is showing  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: when i try to
>   run it on android 4.2 version.  Is their is any other way so that i
>   can use subtitles in video view in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use default Android media player. i use ijkPlayer, there also is Vlc lib, Vitamo and many other media players for android. not sure tho if every one of my mentioned players have subtitle adding feature.

Comment: Thanx sir can you suggest few more players for android

Comment: there are many of them. just google it. I didn't find some easy solution. pretty much every player requires NDK tools and at least linux VM to build *.so files.

Comment: Vitamio is a good option and easy to implement.It provides additional features to your Videoview.